# Confusion about location invariance property

Tags: self-study, inference

The author of Introduction To The Theory Of Statistics by ALEXANDER M. MOOD, FRANKLIN A. GRAYBILL, DUANE C. BOSE stated that an estimator $ t(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},.x_{n})$ is said to be location invariant if $t(x_{1}+c, x_{2}+c, x_{3}+c,., x_{n}+c) = t(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},.x_{n})+c$. Which means estimator should be invariant of simple shift. If a constant value is added to all observation then estimator should shifted by the same constant value. Author then showed that sample variance is not a location invariant estimator since we cannot write $s^2$ as $t(x_{1}+c, x_{2}+c, x_{3}+c,., x_{n}+c) = t(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},.x_{n})+c$. This seems right since if we add a constant value to all the observation then it just shifts the location parameter but the variability of the data remains same.
But the author of Introduction to Mathematical Statistics by ROBERT V. HOGG and ALLEN T. CRAIG defined location invariant estimator as $t(x_{1}+c, x_{2}+c, x_{3}+c,., x_{n}+c) = t(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},.x_{n})$. Then said that sample variance $s^2$ is a location invariant statistics since it doesnt depends on location parameter.

At least I understand that these authors are talking two different things. One saying that location parameter should not depend on shift and other saying statistics should not depends on location parameter. But giving the same name location invariant for two different properties doesnt feel right.
So what is location invariant statistics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of many areas in statistics that uses abysmal terminology. According to [most of the rest of the world,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_(mathematics)) an invariant function's values do not change at all when acted on by a group. The first definition you cite decidedly is *not* invariance in this sense: [physicists would call it "covariant."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors) The lesson here is to pay attention (as you are) to the definitions and go on from there, rather than assuming a word always means what you think it does.